find the sides of a rectangle inscribed in a circle
If I inscribe a rectangle in a circle with radius r so that the area of the rectangle is equal to half the area of the circle, how do I calculate the sides of the rectangle in terms of r?
I wrote down: $a \cdot b = \frac{\pi r^2}{2}$
The only relation I see is $(2r)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ but I can't seem to express neither a nor b from only these 2 pieces of info. I could use some help.

You can find both $(a+b)^2$ and $(a-b)^2$ in terms of $r$.

I expressed b with your help and it came out as $r \left( \sqrt{4+\pi} - \sqrt{4-\pi} \right) \times \frac{1}{2}$ . I basically expressed the $(2r)^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab$
and $(2r)^2 = (a-b)^2 + 2ab$ and replaced ab with half of the area of the circle. That was your idea right? The answer I got does not agree with the solutions in the textbook though...

As you noted, inscribing a rectangle with side lengths a and b inside of a circle with radius r, forms a right triangle where the hypotenuse is $2r$, thus giving us the relation:
$4r^2=a^2+b^2$
Using the comment of peterwhy as inspiration, we know that:
$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$
Given that the area of the rectangle is equal to the area of the circle, namely:
$ab=\frac{{\pi}r^2}{2}$, which we can rewrite nicely as $2ab={\pi}r^2$
Thus,
$(a+b)^2=(a^2+b^2)+(2ab)=4r^2+{\pi}r^2$
$\implies$
$(a+b)^2=4r^2+{\pi}r^2$
we can equivalently say that:
$(a+b)^2=({r}\sqrt{4+\pi})^2$
We can square root both sides, taking only the positive option, and yield that:
$a+b={r}\sqrt{4+\pi}$
Equivalently, computing $(a-b)^2$, we get:
$a-b={r}\sqrt{4-\pi}$
Solving for a, we get:
$2a=(a+b)+(a-b)={r}\sqrt{4+\pi}+{r}\sqrt{4-\pi}$, so
$a=\frac{1}{2}({r}\sqrt{4+\pi}+{r}\sqrt{4-\pi})$
Equivalently,
$b=\frac{1}{2}({r}\sqrt{4+\pi}-{r}\sqrt{4-\pi})$
I am unsure what solution your textbook gives, but it seems to me this is correct, as with these expressions:
$ab=\frac{1}{2}({r}\sqrt{4+\pi}+{r}\sqrt{4-\pi}) * \frac{1}{2}({r}\sqrt{4+\pi}-{r}\sqrt{4-\pi})$
$=\frac{r^2}{4}(\sqrt{4+\pi}+{r}\sqrt{4-\pi})(\sqrt{4+\pi}-{r}\sqrt{4-\pi}) $
note the $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$ form of the parentheses. Thus:
$=\frac{r^2}{4}[(4+\pi) - (4-\pi)]=\frac{2\pi{r}^2}{4}=\frac{\pi{r}^2}{2}$
If you are able, could you share what solution your textbook provided? Perhaps they are equivalent, or I am overlooking something.

It's a (I'm now noticing) a pretty bad highschool textbook. I found quite a lot of mistakes. The answer in the textbook is a what seems like an incorrect approximation: b = 0.84r and a = 1.76r. Anyways, thank you for the help

@Mixoftwo if you squint those are close enough I guess, lol. No problem; most thanks to peterwhy for the critical idea. Happy mathing.
